# How Access angular passed parameters in django views

Tags: javascript, angularjs, django, django-views

I was trying to post the data using angular $http.post method in django,i wanted to know how will i access that parameter value in my django views:-

Here is my controller.js

```
    var nameSpace = angular.module("ajax", ['ngCookies']);

nameSpace.controller("MyFormCtrl", ['$scope', '$http', '$cookies',
function ($scope, $http, $cookies) {
    $http.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
    // To send the csrf code.
    $http.defaults.headers.post['X-CSRFToken'] = $cookies.get('csrftoken');

    // This function is called when the form is submitted.
    $scope.submit = function ($event) {
        // Prevent page reload.
        $event.preventDefault();
        // Send the data.
        var in_data = jQuery.param({'content': $scope.card.content,'csrfmiddlewaretoken': $cookies.csrftoken});
        $http.post('add_card/', in_data)
          .then(function(json) {
            // Reset the form in case of success.
            console.log(json.data);
            $scope.card = angular.copy({});
        });
    }
 }]);
```

Here is what i am attempting to access those in my view function:-

```
card.content =request.POST.get('content')
```

where card is my model's object,But i am getting NameError: name 'content' is not defined,Please help me out!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using without the jquery Param. Try to pass the simple object in the $http.post(url, data, config)

```
    var nameSpace = angular.module("ajax", ['ngCookies']);

nameSpace.controller("MyFormCtrl", ['$scope', '$http', '$cookies',
function ($scope, $http, $cookies) {
    $http.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
    // To send the csrf code.
    $http.defaults.headers.post['X-CSRFToken'] = $cookies.get('csrftoken');

    // This function is called when the form is submitted.
    $scope.submit = function ($event) {
        // Prevent page reload.
        $event.preventDefault();
        // Send the data.
        var config = {
            headers : {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8;'
            }
        }
        var in_data = {content: $scope.card.content,csrfmiddlewaretoken: $cookies.csrftoken};
        $http.post('add_card/', in_data, config)
          .then(function(json) {
            // Reset the form in case of success.
            console.log(json.data);
            $scope.card = angular.copy({});
        });
    }
 }]);
```

Comment: should i change my views.py also??@agam

Comment: @VinitRaj No Need to change the view.py file